# get only changed objects from observed array with rxjs

Tags: redux, rxjs

I have an array of objects (not primitives) called "streaks" on my state tree and I want to observe *only* the changes to that array, not simply emit the entire array every time it changes.  When I try this using `pairwise()` I get two identical arrays every time, even though I thought pairwise() would join the previous version and the current version.  Why is pairwise() sending two identical arrays?  **NOTE** `streaks[1]` and `streaks[0]` are identical, so `_.differenceBy()` isn't finding any changes because the two arrays are the same.

```
import {from} from "rxjs";
import {map, pairwise} from "rxjs/operators";
import * as _ from 'lodash';

  const state$ = from(store);
  const streaks$ = state$.pipe(
      map(state => state.streaks),
      // distinctUntilChanged(), <-- i've tried this and nothing is output at all
      pairwise(),
      map(streaks => {
        let diff = _.differenceBy(streaks[0], streaks[1], _.isEqual);
        console.log('diff', diff); //<-- this is an empty array
        return diff;
      })
  );

  streaks$.subscribe((streaksArray) => {
    console.log('STREAKS$ 0', streaksArray); //<-- this is never even hit
  } );
```

Comment: I've had a similar issue and libraries on npm where not good enough IMO so I built my own. Here the demo, hopefully it helps https://stackblitz.com/edit/array-diff

Comment: To figure out whether the problem is rx.js or lodash, what's contained out in streaks[0] and streaks[1]? If they are changing as expected, then this should be lodash question in title and tag

Comment: @Tom streaks[0] and streaks[1] are identical.  i've updated the question to clarify this and therefore that my issue is with rx.js.

Comment: @TylerJones How do you modify the state in your reducer? It sounds like you don't make a deep copy and use maybe just spread operator `...` that make a shallow copy. This way you're modifying the same instance that is saved inside `distinctUntilChanged`. If you always `_.cloneDeep` each `streaks` in your reducer you should be able to compare them with `distinctUntilChanged(_.isEqual)`.

Comment: This would also explain why `pairwise()` is giving you two identical arrays.

Comment: @martin yes, my issue was a combination of this, plus the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by creating an *distinctUntilChanged**Array*** operator that uses a self written *compareArray* function

**Create compare array function**

```
const compareArray<T> = (first: T[], second: T[], comparator=: (obj: T, obj2: T) => boolean): boolean {
  return (first.length === 0 && second.length === 0)
    || (first.length === second.length && first.every((value, index) => {
         return comparator
           ? comparator(value, second[index])
           : JSON.stringify(value) === JSON.stringify(second[index]);
    }))
}
```

*Maybe you find a better array comparator. This is just my personal implementation of it*

**Create distinctUntilChangedArray operator**

```
const distinctUntilChangedArray<T> = (comparator?: (prev: T, curr: T) => boolean): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T[]> {
  return distinctUntilChanged((prev: T[], curr: T[]) => {
    return compareArray(first, second, comparator);
  }
}
```

**Final usage**

```
interface nonPrimitive {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const nonPrimitiveComparator = (prev: nonPrimitive, curr: nonPrimitive): boolean => {
  return prev.id === curr.id && prev.name === curr.name;
}

const source$: Observable<nonPrimitive>;

const distinctedSource$ = source$.pipe(
  distinctUntilChangedArray(nonPrimitiveComparator)
);
```